# More efficient way of loading and editing (via TextBoxes) lines in a text-based file

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, winforms, file-io

Currently, my program (http://1drv.ms/1k1jVND) loads into two string arrays (one 'In', one 'Out') all the lines from a file (examples included in the 'Data' folder of the above archive) via `File.ReadAllLines()`, and then each line is copied from the array into the appropriate WinForms TextBox:

```
string file;
public string[] linesIn;
public string[] linesOut;
.........
.........
linesIn = File.ReadAllLines(file);
linesOut = linesIn 
.........
.........
textBox10.Text = linesIn[27];
```

Then, when it comes time to save the file, I write the contents of each textbox into the appropriate place in the 'Out' array:

```
linesOut[27] = textBox10.Text
```

(The reason for having the two arrays is that I thought it might be an easy way to implement a 'revert' functionality for if the user wanted the original values after having already saved over the file they loaded; This functionality has not been implemented yet and, now that I think of it, I don't know if I ever will actually do it so, in answering this question, feel free to consider it expendable)

This seems like it is far from the most efficient way of doing things and, as I'm planning on rewriting the whole thing as WPF program anyway, I was hoping someone might be able to tell me a better way of going about it.

I was wondering if there might be a way of 'linking' each TextBox to the appropriate Array index, such that changes to the TextBox automatically update the Array contents? (Short of having about 120 TextChanged events)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest to go with MVVM route. On your ViewModel you have a property that hold your PreviousValue as well as CurrentValue (or whatever name you think appropriate and then utilize the power of Binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to map txtBox0 to array item 0 and so on, you could do the following. 
This would be for load the text boxes. A similar method for saving. 
Where txtBox(n) is your naming convention for text boxes and your container for the textboxes is Form1.

```
int i = 0;
for(i=0; i < linesIn.Count-1;i++)
{
    TextBox t = (TextBox)Form1.Controls.Find("txtBox"+i);
    t.Text = linesIn[i];

}
```